# Hey, I tried to make a little code but it always says this: Error:(17, 26) java: no suitable constructor found for String(java.io.InputStream)

Tags: java

I tried to make this code to help me in German class. But it keeps giving me the same Error:

Error:(17, 26)

```
java: no suitable constructor found for String(java.io.InputStream)
constructor java.lang.String.String(java.lang.String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; java.io.InputStream cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
```

Code:
            Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
            String b = a.nextLine();

```
        if (b.equals("ich")) {
            System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
            Scanner ich = new Scanner(System.in);
            String ich1 = ich.nextLine();
        }
        else if (b.equals("du")){
            System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
            Scanner du = new Scanner(System.in);
            String du1 = new String(System.in);
        }
        else if (b.equals("er")){
            System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
            Scanner ese = new Scanner(System.in);
            String ese1 = ese.nextLine();

        }
```

}
    }

Comment: Did you mean `du.nextLine()` instead of `new String(System.in)`?

Comment: `new String(System.in)` isn't the correct way of getting user input.

Comment: Also, you're doing almost the exact same thing in each of the cases. Why bother with the `if` statements at all if you're always going to do the same thing regardless? Did you mean to do this, or are the `print` statements supposed to be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on logic, where for all of the cases you have:

- printing output (using `println()`)
- creating new variable (`new Scanner()`)
- reading data from the console (`nextLine();`)

maybe you used wrong method or call?

```
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
String b = a.nextLine();

if (b.equals("ich")) {
    System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
    Scanner ich = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ich1 = ich.nextLine();
} else if (b.equals("du")) {
    System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
    Scanner du = new Scanner(System.in);
    // MAYBE MISTAKE THERE?
    String du1 = du.nextLine();
} else if (b.equals("er")) {
    System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
    Scanner ese = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ese1 = ese.nextLine();
}
```

All of the cases are that same, so you can make it simpler:

```
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
String b = a.nextLine();

switch (b) {
    case "ich":
        System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
        break;
    case "du":
        System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
        break;
    case "er":
        System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");
        break;
}

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String readedString = scanner.nextLine();
```

or even simpler:

```
System.out.println("Bitte gib ein Verb ein");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String readedString = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try.